# Changing the background color for my code snippet

Tags: master-page, page-layout, css

I have added  code snippet to my team site containing the following code:-

```
<div class="ms-comm-adminLinks ms-core-defaultFont ms-noList" unselectable="on"> 
  <div class="ms-webpart-titleText" unselectable="on"> Useful Links </div> 
<ul class="ms-comm-adminLinksList" unselectable="on"> 

<ul unselectable="on">

 <li class="ms-comm-adminLinksListItem" unselectable="on"><a href="https://login.salesforce.com/" target="_blank" unselectable="on"> Salesforce </a></li>
//code goes here
  </ul>
</ul></div>
```

but this will have the defualt light-grey back ground color as shown below. so is there a way to modify this background color without affecting the ms-comm-adminLinks `ms-core-defaultFont ms-noList` format ?

[image]

**EDIT**

I have added the following to my custom CSS file:-

```
.ms-comm-adminLinks {
    background-color:#008CD2 !important;
    }
    .ms-comm-adminLinksListItem a{
    color:white;
    }
    .ms-webpart-titleText{
    color:white !important;
    }
```

And it chnage the format as needed,  so is this approach wrong or considered risky, and the result is now as follow:-
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just wrap it in an element with a specific CSS class?

```
<ul>
  <!-- snipped -->
  <li class="ms-comm-adminLinksListItem" unselectable="on"><a href="https://login.salesforce.com/" target="_blank" unselectable="on"> Salesforce </a></li>
  <div class="codeSnippet">
     //code goes here
  </div>
</ul>
```

You could then style the `codeSnippet` class any way you liked.

Comment: can you check my Edit please ?

Comment: It is generally a bad idea to override styles from Microsoft though there are times when it is necessary.  Since you are just changing the color, this should be acceptable though I would have tried to find a more specific selector first, something like `.MyLeftCol .ms-comm-adminlinks { /* style stuff */ }`